Есть ли разница между эффективностью распределения с использованием потоков и процессов?
Есть 4-ядерный процессор и некая программа. Если выполнять некую программу в одном процессе, то мы не используем мощности всего процессора, будет много переключений контекста. Чтобы повысить эффективность мы можем:

А) Создать 4 процесса по 1 главному потоку в каждом
Б) Создать 1 процесс с 4-мя потоками

В интернете пишут, что разницы в эффективности не будет. Это бы означало, что разницы между потоком и процессом нет, то есть они взаимозаменяемы и ядро может захватить поток созданный внутри процесса и использовать как главный поток в другом процессе, то есть просто использовать как процесс. Однако мне показалось это странным т.к. насколько я понял потоки внутри процесса не могут выполняться по-настоящему одновременно - внутри одного процесса потоки делят ресурсы и выполняются в пересекающиеся промежутки времени посредством переключения контекста, что означает, что вариант Б) будет менее эффективен.
Так вот резюмируя:

Будут ли варианты А) и Б) одинаковы по эффективности и почему?
Взаимозаменяемы ли потоки и процессы, то есть может ли поток созданный внутри процесса стать отдельным процессом? Может есть какая-то другая причина почему варианты А) и Б) будут одинаковы по эффективности?


"потоки делят ресурсы" - какие?

@andreymal
Например, оперативную память

Ну вас в принципе никто не заставляет использовать одну и ту же память в нескольких потоках

Если процессы/потоки исполняются (почти) не зависят друг от друга по данным, то разницы по эффективности не будет. Если они обмениваются данными при расчётах, то одна многопоточная программа может быть более эффективной.

Архитектурная рекомендация - запустить несколько однопоточных процессов. Просто потому что однопоточные вычисления гораздо легче отладить и оптимизировать.

@andreymal
То есть  потоки никак жестко не привязаны к процессу в котором они были созданы, и в варианте Б) потоки становятся отдельными процессами?

С точки зрения какого-нибудь линукса между процессами и потоками нет вообще никакой разницы, просто у потоков есть немножко общей памяти. Но если эта память используется только для чтения, то и делить её (то есть синхронизировать доступ каким-нибудь мьютексом или вроде того) нет необходимости и браться тормозам вроде бы некуда

Ну и да, между разными процессами на самом деле тоже есть общая память, как минимум потому что динамические библиотеки (dll/so) загружаются один раз и переиспользуются во всех процессах. Но, конечно, они тоже доступны только для чтения

Грубо говоря, процесс - это поток со своей отдельной памятью. Вот из-за того, как эта отдельная память выделяется, копируется или что там с ней делается - потоки более тяжеловесные, чем процессы. В остальном особой разницы нет. Переключение между потоками одного процесса происходит проще - не нужно ничего делать с памятью.

@CrazyElf, опечатка про тяжеловесность?

@user207200 Да, конечно, наоборот - потоки более легковесные )
